# Why does SocketIO connect multiple times to server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

This is the code on client,

```
const url = "localhost:8080"

const socket = socketIOClient(url);

socket.on("broadcast", (value) => {
    this.props.getUpdate(value)
})
```

This is the code on Server nodejs express,

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('A user connected');
    
});
```

the console.log on the server is running more than once intervally i dont know why?

note: client is react with redux

edit:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = "localhost:8080"

    const socket = socketIOClient(url);

    socket.on("broadcast", (value) => {
        this.props.getUpdate(value)
    })
}
```

I just create socket in componentDidMount function.

https://github.com/Mrbiyik/platraFrontend
this is the repo of this code

edit:

[image]

It is creating this request intervally

Comment: Please show the rest of your client code. You're probably creating a new socket again and again. You can click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66386158/edit) to add details to your question.

Comment: I have edited can you check again?

Comment: If you add a `console.log('socket')` below `const socket = ....`, does it get called more than once in your console? What does `this.props.getUpdate` do? Does it cause the socket component to unmount and remount?

Comment: I have added console.log to the componentdidmount but it is printed just once and also getUpdate is about the redux. In addition, this code was working fine last year.

Comment: this is not multiple connections! this is just a ping pong polling for checking live connection. maybe check every per 25 second

Comment: why does server side run the console log every time?